# Azure App Gateway Missing Forward Headers

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, api-gateway

I have setup an Azure App Gateway WAF v2 instance in front of my asp.net web api running on Azure App Service. In order to get this to work, I had to turn on the following option in the backend setting in the rule in AG:

[image: Azure App Gateway Backend Setting]

I have [Http Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?msclkid=cb800b29d0a511ecbf5fd2b26b88175f&view=aspnetcore-6.0) turned on in my asp.net web api. I am trying to debug/troubleshoot the headers to determine how to get NSwag to render the proper server and base url, however I do not see any of the following headers present which according to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/how-application-gateway-works) should be present:

- x-forwarded-for
- x-forwarded-proto

I do see the following headers:

- x-original-for
- x-original-proto
- x-original-host
- x-original-url

Any ideas on what is missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

App gateway should send thoses headers by default but app service is not reading them by default.

> In some configurations, the App Service is using the App Service FQDN as the redirect URI instead of the Front Door FQDN. This will lead to an issue when the client is being redirected to App Service instead of Front Door. To change that, the forwardProxy setting needs to be set to Standard to make App Service respect the X-Forwarded-Host header set by Azure Front Door.

this is true as well for App Gateway.

Configuration need to be changed either in command line, either by editing the json configuration of the app service directly.

[considerations-when-using-azure-front-door](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#considerations-when-using-azure-front-door:%7E:text=Ensure%20that%20App%20Service%20is%20using%20the%20right%20redirect%20URI)